# Why does DISTINCT within COLLECT() with OPTIONAL MATCH lead to ExecutionFailure since Neo4j 2.3.3?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I updated Neo4j from 2.3.2 to 2.3.3 an since then querys with the following pattern lead to Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (f:DOES_EXIST)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:DOES_NOT_EXIST)
RETURN collect(DISTINCT n.property), collect(DISTINCT f.property)
```

Somehow it worked fine in 2.3.2, does anyone know why and how to solve this? What I want is to query some patterns an return them as distinct collections, which are empty, if the optional pattern doesn't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EDITED]

2.3.3 seems to have a bug (and I have submitted [an issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/6809) for that). This query works around the issue:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (f:DOES_EXIST)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT f.property) AS fProps
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:DOES_NOT_EXIST)
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT n.property) AS nProps, fProps;
```

Comment: Since in your query DISTINCT is not within each COLLECT() statement --> not every collection has distinct elements in case of (optional) matches. But thats my goal...

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to all the items in the same clause, so there is no problem.

Comment: But there is a difference between 

"OPTIONAL MATCH (f:DOES_EXIST)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:DOES_NOT_EXIST)
WITH DISTINCT f.property AS fProp, n.property AS nProp
RETURN COLLECT(fProp), COLLECT(nProp)"

 // and 

"OPTIONAL MATCH (f:DOES_EXIST)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:DOES_NOT_EXIST)
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT f.property), COLLECT(DISTINCT n.property)" Do you agree?